# How do I change a basic counter in react so that multiple copies all maintain the same value?

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

***COUNTER.JS***

```
import React, {useState} from "react";


function Counter() {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const [action, setAction] = useState("");

    const handleCounter = (increase, amount) => {
        setCounter(counter + (increase ? amount : 0 - amount));
        setAction(increase ? "increased" : "decreased");
    }

    return (
        <>
            <h1>{counter}</h1>
            <h1>{action}</h1>
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => handleCounter(true, 1)}
                >increase +1
                </button>

                <button onClick={() => handleCounter(false, 1)}
                >decrease -1
                </button>

                <button onClick={() => handleCounter(true, 10)}
                >increase +10
                </button>

                <button onClick={() => handleCounter(false, 10)}
                >decrease -10
                </button>

            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Counter;
```

*****APP.JS*****

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import './App.css';
import Counter from "./Counter";


function App () {

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1> A BASIC COUNTER</h1>
            <Counter/>
            <Counter/>
            <Counter/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

as you can see this is a basic counter i have made in react but i have made 3 counters what i am trying to do is to make sure they all have the same value at the same time so when i increase one counter by 10 they all increase to 10 could anyone help me do that

Comment: Please check it - [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Create state in app.js file and pass common function from app.js to each instance of counter to manipulate it's value onClick.

App.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import './App.css';
import Counter from "./Counter";


function App () {
 const[counter,setCounter]=useState(0);
 const [action, setAction] = useState("");

 const handleCounter = (increase, amount) => {
    setCounter(counter + (increase ? amount : 0 - amount));
    setAction(increase ? "increased" : "decreased");
  }
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1> A BASIC COUNTER</h1>
            <Counter 
              counter={counter} 
              handleCounter={(increase,amount)=>handleCounter(increase,amount)} 
              action={action}
              />
            <Counter 
              counter={counter} 
             handleCounter={(increase,amount)=>handleCounter(increase,amount)} 
              action={action}
              />
            <Counter 
              counter={counter} 
              handleCounter={(increase,amount)=>handleCounter(increase,amount)} 
              action={action}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Counter.js

```
import React from "react";


function Counter({counter,handleCounter,action}) {
    
    return (
        <>
            <h1>{counter}</h1>
            <h1>{action}</h1>
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => handleCounter(true, 1)}
                >increase +1
                </button>

                <button onClick={() => handleCounter(false, 1)}
                >decrease -1
                </button>

                <button onClick={() => handleCounter(true, 10)}
                >increase +10
                </button>

                <button onClick={() => handleCounter(false, 10)}
                >decrease -10
                </button>

            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Counter;
```

Comment: could you please write out the code that i can try will be very helpful thank you very much

Comment: i am getting an error in app.js  error is '}' expected:21   ')' expected: 40 unexpected syntax

Comment: It was just a simple typo I made earlier , try again.